# Where should I ask about Firefox's behavior regarding client-side certificates?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm sorry to bother you with this, but I don't want the answers to be bogged down in administrative crud. I want to ask if it's possible to set Firefox up so that it serves a given client-side certificate even when it shouldn't (this is for dev/testing purposes).

I'm programming this thing, but it's not a programming question; Firefox connects to a web server, but it's not a web development question; it has to do with certificates, but it's not a cryptography question. So what's the best place to ask?

Comment: Questions about how to configure end-user software belong on Super User.

Comment: What do you mean by “when it shouldn’t”? When the server doesn’t ask for one, when it’s the wrong host, …?

Comment: Perhaps the Firefox dev mailing list?

Comment: This is becoming hilarious. Where should I ask questions about where I should I ask questions? Oh, hang on – I had posted this question on Meta, and someone decided to move it to Stack Overflow, where it was deemed off topic. The ways of bureaucracy...